# Returning entries from Firebase are undefined

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a component in angular that is supposed to display items from Firebase in a table via a service:

```
<table class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <th>Animal Name</th>
    <th>Species</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Last Fed</th>
    <th>Last Shed</th>
    <th>Diet</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </thead>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let animal of animalsArray"></ng-container>
  <tr>
    <td>{{animal.animalName}}</td>
    <td>{{animal.species}}</td>
    <td>{{animal.age}}</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AnimalsService } from '../animals.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-animal-board',
  templateUrl: './animal-board.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./animal-board.component.scss']
})
export class AnimalBoardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private animalService: AnimalsService) {}
  animalsArray = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.animalService.getAnimals().subscribe(
      list => {
        this.animalsArray = list.map(item => {
          return {
            $key: item.key,
            ...item.payload.val()
          }
        })
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that the table is empty without my Firebase entries, and it gives me this error:

```
AnimalBoardComponent.html:13 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'animalName' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (AnimalBoardComponent.html:13)
```

What am I doing wrong that makes animalName undefined?

here is also the service that I use to inject:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AnimalsService {

  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  animalList: AngularFireList<any>

  form = new FormGroup({
    $key: new FormControl(null),
    animalName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    species: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    age: new FormControl(''),
    lastFed: new FormControl(''),
    lastShed: new FormControl(''),
    diet: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    comments: new FormControl('')
  });

  getAnimals() {
    this.animalList = this.firebase.list('animals');
    return this.animalList.snapshotChanges();
  }

  insertAnimal(animal) {
     this.animalList.push({
      animalName: animal.animalName,
      species: animal.species,
      age: animal.age,
      lastFed: animal.lastFed,
      lastShed: animal.lastShed,
      diet: animal.diet,
      comments: animal.comments
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Add the service code.

Comment: edited my question

Comment: you are getting this error because of ng-container closed before tr please check answer for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have closed `ng-container` at the wrong place. you need to close it after `</tr>` tag so that it will work.

Here is the updated code.

**animal-board.component.html**

```
<table class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <th>Animal Name</th>
    <th>Species</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Last Fed</th>
    <th>Last Shed</th>
    <th>Diet</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </thead>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let animal of animalsArray">
  <tr>
    <td>{{animal.animalName}}</td>
    <td>{{animal.species}}</td>
    <td>{{animal.age}}</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
</table>
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with:

```
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let animal of animalsArray">
       <td>{{animal.animalName}}</td>
       <td>{{animal.species}}</td>
       <td>{{animal.age}}</td>
       <td>
         <button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
         <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
       </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
```

and remove

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let animal of animalsArray"></ng-container>
```